# Do I need DNS Server?

Tags: network-manager, dns, systemd, dnsmasq, hosts

I use internet (personal connection from ISP). My operating System is Ubuntu 18.4. I am aware of /etc/hosts file, but it has limitation with wild card entries (to block websites).

I wanted to know if Ubuntu does caching of DNS or do I need to install some  other tool? There is a Network Manager installed. And Systemd is the daemon manager. Do these tools have ways of managing DNS? Do, I need to use Dnsmasq?

I have read that many people prefer Dnsmasq, but I am not sure why is it preferable? I am not sure if this can already be done  by Networkmanager or systemd.

---

EDIT:

- My goal, is to block websites and do caching of DNS if it is significantly beneficial? Also, I am not a web developer.
- Can I use wildcards to block websites without dnsmasq?
- @earthmeLon questioned: Also, are you trying to block or allow access to more of the Internet? Should you be blacklisting or whitelisting?

  - I am trying to blacklist, as I don't know if I might need to access some other websites in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your system will honor [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live#DNS_records), which 'caches' the response for some time.  You don't want to ignore these values or mess with these at all.

Many people prefer `dnsmasq` (I have to assume) because it gives them more control of the DNS responses.  In most scenarios, `dnsmasq` is set up as a sort of proxy to query other DNS servers for most domains, but allow you to customize or edit certain domains.  [`bind`](https://www.isc.org/downloads/bind/) is a more robust DNS server.

An example would be if you are a developer and (before Google bought `.dev` TLD) you wanted to set up `nic.dev` on your computer or LAN such that the domain resolves to an IP instead of erroring that their is no record.

It's great that you are interested in these technologies, but don't mess up your main system playing around, especially if you're not addressing a problem.  Set up a VM or another system and play around with `dnsmasq` or `bind` if you have the interest or need.

Comment: You asked why people like/use `dnsmasq`.  I was trying to provide an example.  I don't feel you need to be a developer to understand what I mentioned, but maybe you're feeling you don't need `dnsmasq`, because you're not a developer, and that's most likely true.

Comment: How can I check TTL for my system? So, I don't need DNS caching?

Comment: Please read TTL document provided.  Please Google and do a bit of research on your own.  It sounds like you're going to try to adjust TTL values, which is a bad idea.  They are part of DNS records that the administrators of the domain set up.  They know all about DNS and TTL and you should trust their values.  Your system will (by default) hold/cache records for 300s (5m), so no, you do not need anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I use wildcards to block websites without dnsmasq?

Comment: That's a new question.  It depends on your criteria.  Without DNS, `iptables` can block CIDR blocks or specific IPs.  There are many guides out there to set up DNS servers on Linux, even stuff like **pi hole**.  Please let me know if you have a specific question by asking a new question if one arises.

Comment: Also, are you trying to block or allow access to more of the Internet?  Should you be blacklisting or whitelisting? - The point of this question is for you to re-evaluate your position and to provide details why you feel one way is better than the other (ie: give us insight into what you're trying to accomplish).